# On connecting to MySQL via SSL getting ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: protocol version mismatch

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl

I am working with MySQL and generated the certificates to use with MySQL to enable SSL.

Here are SSL configs:

```
mysql> show variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                      |
+---------------+----------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                        |
| have_ssl      | YES                        |
| ssl_ca        | /etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem     |
| ssl_capath    |                            |
| ssl_cert      | /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                            |
| ssl_key       | /etc/mysql/server-key.pem  |
+---------------+----------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It seems to be working fine and looks like I did it well with applying the certificates with the MySQL server.

The problem exists with creating connection to MySQL server via remote host.

```
mysql -u app1 -p -h 192.168.33.131 --ssl --ssl-capath=<path>/ssl/ --ssl-ca=<path>/ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=<path>/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=<path>/client-key.pem
Enter password:
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: protocol version mismatch
```

Seems to be having some issues with certificates or may be something else.

**Environment:**

```
  OS:      Ubuntu 14.04
  MySQL:   5.5.41
  OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```